# Which gap between primes can be reached under $EH[0.8]$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-gaps

This question is a follow-up to [Would Elliott-Halberstam conjecture follow from GRH?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153078/would-elliott-halberstam-conjecture-follow-from-grh)

Assuming any $\theta<1-\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is the de Bruijn-Newman constant is an exponent of distribution of the primes, which bounded gap between primes can be reached from Platt and Trudgian's upper bound $\Lambda\leq 0.2$? The best known such gap so far is $246$, which can be reduced to $12$ under the full Elliott-Halberstam conjecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand matters, the only way to get an explicit bound for gaps between consecutive primes (not strings of $m$ consecutive primes for some $m\geq 3$) using that particular level of distribution that is optimal relative to the method is to completely rework everything in

- DHJ Polymath, *Variants of the Selberg sieve, and bounded intervals containing many primes*, Research in the Mathematical Sciences volume 1, Article number: 12 (2014), doi:[10.1186/s40687-014-0012-7](https://doi.org/10.1186/s40687-014-0012-7)

with $\theta < 0.8$, computing a large number of the implied constants and choosing a new admissible set relative the the level of distribution you have selected.  Computing the implied constants is straightforward but tedious.  Finding the optimal admissible set sounds a bit more computationally expensive (but completely doable).